# Signal processing question explanation

Tags: signal-processing

We have the system :

$$y(k)= |x(k)| +x(-k) + 2x(k-2)$$

In my book it says that this system is not causal and also not stable. I would like a detailed explanation.

Edit : its y(k)

Comment: What do you mean by $y(x)$?

Comment: Output of the function

Comment: Did you mean to write $y_k$ or something similar?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $y(k)$ instead of $y(x)$?  Otherwise, how is $y(k)$ defined?  And if $x \not \in \Bbb Z$, then what?

Comment: This is a standard sort of thing for signal processing; a clearer notation might be
$$
y[x(k)] = |x(k)| + x(-k) + 2x(k-2)
$$

Comment: I am sorry its y(k)

Comment: The system is BIBO stable.  Is there some other definition of stability that you're using?  If so, please clarify what you mean by "stable".

Comment: (I read $-k$ as $k-1$. Need new glasses.)

Comment: Causal would mean that if two inputs $x_1,x_2$ match for $k \le k_0$, then the corresponding outputs $y_1, y_2$ should also match for $k \le k_0$. If you take $x_1$ to be zero everywhere and $x_2$ zero everywhere except $1$ at $k=1$, then (letting $k_0 = -1$) we see that $x_1,x_2$ match for $k \le k_0$, but $y_1(k_0) = 0 \neq 1 = y_2(k_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is not causal since, for example, at $k = -1$, the value of $y(k)$ depends of the future value of $x$ at $k = 1$.

The system is [BIBO stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability).  Suppose that $|x(k)| \leq B$ for all $k$, then
$$
|y(k)| = \left||x(k)| + x(-k) + 2x(k-2)\right|\leq B + B + 2B = 4B
$$

Comment: Why is x(-k)=B?

Comment: I don't know what $x(-k)$ is, but I know that $|x(-k)| \leq B$ since $|x(k)|\leq B$ no matter what $k$ happens to be.

Comment: Ah I see thanks man